# ZedGraph doesn't works in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, components, zedgraph

Anyone used ZedGraph in VS2012 ?? When i try load component i get error message that "There are not Component in zedgraph.dll that can be placed on toolbox".

I can't find info does zedgraph works on VS2012.

Please recommend me some library to plot graph of math functions, thx

Answer (score 4):

You first need to add the `ZedGraphControl` to your toolbox. The instructions on the *Zedgraph* [CodeProject page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5431/A-flexible-charting-library-for-NET) works for Visual Studio 2012 as well:

> ZedGraph is accessible as a control from the control toolbox in Visual Studio .NET. To access ZedGraph, first launch Visual Studio .NET, and create a new Windows Application (Forms) project. Open the form design so that it appears in the current window. View the toolbox using the View/Toolbox menu command. Right-click inside the "General" or "Components" sub-pane of the tool box, and select the "Choose Items..." option. Click "Browse...", and navigate to the *ZedGraph.dll* file. Once this file is added, you should see a `ZedGraphControl` option in the toolbox.

If you want to use an alternative charting library, please be aware that .NET 4 and later contains the .NET Charting library for Windows Forms out-of-the-box, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.aspx).

Comment: VS 2019, I'm unable to add it to the toolbox. Old projects that are using the control works ok, but it still doesn't show up in the toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to nuget package manager console and:
Install-Package ZedGraph

It will install what you need and it will be working